# $xy= z^2$ and $x, y$ are individual squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We know that concatenation of $xy = z^2$ for $x = 4^2 = 16$ and $y = 3^2 = 9$. Here $169 = 13^2 \implies z = 13$. Now my question is how to prove this is the first such set of positive integers $(x, y, z) = (16, 9, 13)$ for concatenation of $xy = z^2$? Or disprove if it is not such first set of pairs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about $49 = 7^{2}$, which is the concatenation of $2^{2} = 4$ and $3^{2} = 9$?

Comment: Awertheim! I taken x = 4^2 = 16 and y = 3^2 = 9 and then put together 16 and 9 => 169, which is square of another number. ie., 13.

Comment: Naroza, you asked to show that either your provided tuple $(4, 3, 13)$ was the "first" tuple satisfying your concatenation criteria, or prove that an alternative tuple preceding it exists. I am not sure what metric you are using to define what constitutes the first such tuple, but the tuple $(2, 3, 7)$ provided seems like a decent candidate as a counterexample to your contention.

Comment: Awertheim! Sir, you are correct (2, 3, 7) is the first by your counter example. But, how to prove mathematically, this is the very first such pair?

Comment: Awertheim! Sir, I am agree with you. I am looking only in set of positive integers, which will satisfy my criteria and saying that (2, 3, 7) is such first pair.

Comment: Well, there aren't too many pairs, excuse me, triples that could come before $(2,3,7)$; you can just check that $(1,1,x)$ and $(1,2,x)$ and so on don't work. But if you want to get someone's attention here, the way to do it is with @ before the name, not with ! after the name.

Comment: Awertheim! Sir, I think I given more clarity. please discuss. your discussions are very important for me to learn something new from you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson! I understand now. I will put @ before the name only. (1, 1, x) is not satisfying my criteria. To prove that (2, 3, 7) is first pair, what to do. Please direct to me.

Comment: @GerryMyerson! Sir, for (1, 1, x), 1^ 2 = 1, and 1^2 = 1 now 11 is not square of any positive integer.

Comment: @Naroza_lary_sai, it looks like GerryMyerson's hint is the best course of action to me. Sadly, I don't have any other suggestions than that - eliminating smaller possible counterexamples seems like the most reasonable course of action to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your idea of "first" is based on the last numbre, i.e. if $(a,b,c)$ is a triple of positive integers where the concatenation of $a^2$ and $b^2$ gives $c^2$, and $(d,e,f) $ is another such triple, then $(a,b,c)$ comes before $(d,e,f)$ if $c<f$. Note that $c=f$ mmight be possible even with different triples.

We see by inspection that $(2,3,7)$ is a triple satisfying your criteria.
Any triple $(a,b,c)$ coming before that must have $c\le 6$. As one readily checks, $36,25,16,9,4,1$ cannot be written as concatenation of positive squares.

---

A quick computer search reveals as first solutions:
$$ (2,3,7), 
(4,3,13), 
(6,1,19), 
(1,15,35), 
(12,2,38), 
(4,9,41), 
(18,3,57), 
(2,15,65), 
(2,30,70),\\
(1,75,125), 
(4,30,130), 
(6,10,190), 
(2,45,205), 
(7,27,223), 
(80,3,253), 
(9,15,285),\ldots$$
Note that each solution $(a,b,c)$ gives rise to $(a,10b,10c)$.

Comment: ! first of all thank you so much for your answer. we know, there are many such pairs exist. can we find the best possible ever biggest pair, which is satisfy my criteria? I mean the best big one

Comment: ! great sir. I got more interest to learn. How you got such list of pairs? Mainly how each solution (a, b, c) gives rise to (a, 10b, 10c)? what are the relation there between (a, b, c) and (a, 10b, 10c)? how you got these 10's?

Comment: ! Sir, don't loose me of faith, trust on math and on you. I am learning so much interesting things from you by this site. Please discuss the relation of (a, b, c) and (a, 10b, 10c) and also tell me how you got such more pairs. you may think, I am very poor in math. But, with your guidance, I can learn and excel like you on one day. Please...

Comment: Sir, don't loose me of faith, trust on math and on you. I am learning so much interesting things from you by this site. Please discuss the relation of (a, b, c) and (a, 10b, 10c) and also tell me how you got such more pairs. you may think, I am very poor in math. But, with your guidance, I can learn and excel like you on one day. Please...

Comment: The square of $10b$ is the square of $b$ with two zeroes appended, same for $10c$. Thus if the concatenation of $a^2 $ and $b^2$ gives $c^2$, then the concatenation of $a^2 $ and $(10b)^2$ gives $(10c)^2$. And I found my solutions (after the simple inital manual test that $(2,3,7)$ is minimal) by `for(c=1,300,cc=c^2;m=10;while(m<cc,if(cc%m>=m/10 && issquare(cc % m) && issquare(cc\m),print([sqrtint(cc\m),sqrtint(cc%m),c]));m*=10))` in PARI/GP, nothing very elaborate.